# Horrizontal errorbar in ggplot width is not adjusting

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am plotting a point with vertical and horizontal error bars. With the argument width=0.1 I can change the end of the vertical errorbar to adjust but the same command is not working for the horizontal bar (errorbarh). What could I do to fix it?

Comment: The documentation is very clear that is uses `height` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_errorbarh.html

Answer (score 2):

`geom_errorbarh` doesn't have a `width` parameter.  It is the `height` we need to change.  According to `?geom_errorbarh`

> ‘geom_errorbarh’ understands the following aesthetics (required
>        aesthetics are in bold):
>
> ```
>     • *‘xmin’*
>
>     • *‘xmax’*
>
>     • *‘y’*
>
>     • ‘alpha’
>
>     • ‘colour’
>
>     • ‘group’
>
>     • ‘height’
>
>     • ‘linetype’
>
>     • ‘size’
> ```

Using the example from the documentation

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(resp, trt, colour = group))
p + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = resp + se, xmin = resp-se, height = 0.1))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(
   trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
   resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
   group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
   se = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2)
 )
```